# How to print out all constraints constant in Swift IOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I can able to print out **main view** constraints constant by using,

```
for v in view.constraints {
    print(v.constant)
}
```

but it will not iterate through **subviews** to print their constraints too.
so for that, i have...

```
for subview in view.subviews {
    for v in subview.constraints {
        print(v.constant)
    }
}
```

now the question is **what if the subview is a view itself?**. in this case, how to print out the subview->view constraint constants. may be the view which is in subview may have its own subview and so on...

To fix this issue , 
i can simply create outlets for all views and then i have to iterate them one by one to get its constraint constants.

but i feel there must be easy way to print out all constraint constants ( *all the constraints which are created in storyboard under particular view controller* ) full programatically without creating outlets.

**In short :**

How to Print out all the storybaord constraint constants from view controller 
please note : the view controller may have several views and subviews and the subviews may have it own subviews. so we need to create an algorithm which will work efficiently in printing out constraint constant in any type of viewcontrollers if used.

Comment: Note its usually easier to use the view debugger

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a general-purpose recursive traversal method

```
extension UIView {
    func callRecursively(level: Int = 0, _ body: (_ subview: UIView, _ level: Int) -> Void) {
        body(self, level)
        subviews.forEach { $0.callRecursively(level: level + 1, body) }
    }
}
```

you can get your output with

```
    view.callRecursively { subview, level in
        for constraint in subview.constraints {
            print(String(repeating: " ", count: level),  constraint.constant)
        }
    }
```

The  each output line is indented according to the nesting level
in  the view hierarchy.

---

Another example how that recursive method can be used: Find all
subviews of a certain type:

```
    view.callRecursively { subview, _ in
        if let label = subview as? UILabel {
            print(label.text ?? "<none>")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes.  His description is a textbook recursion case.  Nice general-purpose implementation!

Comment: @Martin R . thanks for answering i not tested it yet but i have one doubt. in other answers they used "constraint.constant" ( which indirectly means i can also do constraint.constant = constant + 10 ( some type of changes in constant ) ) how can i do the same with your answer?

Comment: @SatizhJ: See update. It is just a matter of `for in` vs `forEach`.

Comment: @SatizhJ: Actually you could do `$0.constant += 10` in the previous version as well.

Answer (score 6):

This is a perfect place to use recursion.  Write a `printConstraintConstants(for:)` function and have it print out the constants for the current view and have it call itself for all subviews of the current view:

```
func printConstraintConstants(for view: UIView) {
    for constraint in view.constraints {
        print(constraint.constant)
    }

    for subview in view.subviews {
        printConstraintConstants(for: subview)
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems we had the same thoughts ... :)

Answer (score 3):

You may go with breadth-first search with a queue. Of course the initial view should be the top-most in the hierarchy in order to reach every view.

```
var allViews : [UIView] = []

allViews.append(self.view) // Add the top-most view first

while allViews.count > 0 {
    let currentView = allViews.removeFirst()

    allViews.append(contentsOf: currentView.subviews)

    for constraint in currentView.constraints {
        print(constraint.constant)
    }
}
```

Comment: seems to be working along with other answers but let me test it out before accepting any answer. thanks guys :)