# How to delete view constraints of xib in code?

Tags: ios, swift, xib, snapkit

There is a view in xib with it's constranits, I want to remake it's constranits with SnapKit:

```
self.redView.snp.remakeConstraints { (make) in
    make.left.equalToSuperview()
    make.top.equalTo(300)
    make.width.height.equalTo(100)
}
```

However, the console print:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
```

Then I check SnapKit issues and get:

> SnapKit will never touch a constraint that was not made by SnapKit this is by design because SnapKit relies on complete ownership from creation for all of it's features.

So I wonder is where any way I can delete a view's all constranits of xib?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47620352/14733292. Retrieve all constraint and uninstalled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all constraints affecting a UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418884/remove-all-constraints-affecting-a-uiview)